# Обьясните задачу на массивы

Tags: c++, массивы

Одна из задач на зачёте на сессии. Сижу над ней больше недели, не могу никак понять.

Даны натуральное число n (n≥2) и действительный квадратный массив размера nхn. Построить последовательность b1, b2, ..., bn  из нулей  и единиц, в которой  bi = 1 тогда и только тогда, когда элементы i-й строки матрицы образуют возрастающую последовательность.

Comment: И что тут непонятно? Массив NxN имеете? проходите по строкам, проверяя, растут ли значения в пределах строки. Если да - в массив b пишете 1, нет - 0. **Что** непонятно?

Comment: @Harry , а, то есть просто сравниваем элементы в строке и если каждый следующий больше предыдущего, то строка эквивалентна 1? Звучит даже слишком просто как-то -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть массив arr

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 flag=1;
 for (j=0;j<n-1&&flag==1;j++)
 if (arr[i][j+1]<=arr[i][j]) flag=0;
 b[i]=flag;
 }
```

Собственно ввод вывод легко написать самому.

Comment: Кто минусовал, обьясните в чем проблема. Мне, например это интересно...

Comment: Кстати да. Интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать готовый алгоритм:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        b[i] = std::is_sorted(arr[i], arr[i] + n);
```